High number of loops in within a nested loop Index Scan
Query
SELECT
  organizations.lf_id,
  organizations.eb_id
FROM
  organizations
  JOIN organization_lists_organizations ON organizations.id = organization_lists_organizations.organization_id
  WHERE organization_lists_organizations.organization_list_id = 1
ORDER BY organization_lists_organizations.id DESC
LIMIT 100000;

Plan
Limit  (cost=761732.74..773038.06 rows=96896 width=51) (actual time=135.754..161.078 rows=100000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=523093                       
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=761732.74..773038.06 rows=96896 width=51) (actual time=135.753..153.552 rows=100000 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2                       
        Workers Launched: 2                      
        Buffers: shared hit=523093               
        ->  Sort  (cost=760732.71..760853.83 rows=48448 width=51) (actual time=133.101..134.706 rows=33874 loops=3)
              Sort Key: organization_lists_organizations.id DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3492kB
              Buffers: shared hit=523093         
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3482kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3507kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1458.28..756962.45 rows=48448 width=51) (actual time=0.844..125.618 rows=34670 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=523079   
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on organization_lists_organizations  (cost=1457.71..358530.13 rows=48448 width=16) (actual time=0.831..7.790 rows=34670 loops=3)
                          Recheck Cond: (organization_list_id = 350065)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=963
                          Buffers: shared hit=3032
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_organization_lists_organizations_on_organization_list_id  (cost=0.00..1428.64 rows=116276 width=0) (actual time=2.145..2.146 rows=104018 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (organization_list_id = 350065)
                                Buffers: shared hit=142
                    ->  Index Scan using organizations_pkey on organizations  (cost=0.57..8.22 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=104009)
                          Index Cond: (id = organization_lists_organizations.organization_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=520047
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=355
Planning Time: 0.761 ms
Execution Time: 166.143 ms

Table sizes

organizations: 147_186_773
organization_lists_organizations: 139_640_505

The original query took over 10s but as you can see from the plan, it's now using some buffers and the time has decreased. Why is the task Index Scan using organizations_pkey on organizations looping so much? Is it detrimental? Anything I can do to improve the performance?

put the WHERE clause in the ON clause, so that not so much rows have to be joined

@jjanes I apologize. As per my last paragraph, I mean to ask if this is a bad plan or not. I know it's retrieving 100k rows from a table with 100M records but I want to emphasize that the original query (where nothing was cached), took over 10s. It's a heavily used table (both reads and writes)

@nbk Well, I don't think I can do that because I actually want all the organizations that belong to that specific list. Maybe de-normalizing the data would be beneficial here (storing eb_id and lf_id within organization_lists_organizations?

Your query without the LIMIT would apparently return about 104,000 rows, which is then restricted by the LIMIT to 100,000 rows.  That seems like a remarkable coincidence that those two numbers just happen to be so similar. Or is that something more than a coincidence?

It would help to see a plan when it actually is slow.  Could you pick a constant value other than 350065 for organization_list_id, so that it needs data which is not already in cache?  Then make sure track_io_timing is turned on before collecting a new plan.

A hash join might be more effective than a nested loop, but it is not clear.  It is far from obvious that reading 147 million rows efficiently when you only need 104,000 would be faster than hitting an index 104,000 separate times.  (but it would certainly need a lot of RAM to hash all 147 million in memory). You could try it by setting enable_nestloop=off to see what it does instead, but Laurenz's suggestion might be your best option and the first thing to try.

The execution plan is already good. You could create a covering index to reduce the number of table blocks that need to be read:
CREATE INDEX ON organizations (id) INCLUDE (lf_id, eb_id);

VACUUM organizations;

VACUUM is necessary for efficient index-only scans.

The plan is not good to me.

You can get an index scan + sort avoidance instead of the Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on organization_lists_organizations by adding a index on (organization_list_id,id). This should be good enough for you.

You can get optim performance by add other referenced columns to achieve index only on both tables.
CREATE INDEX PAWSQL_IDX1838207686 ON organization_lists_organizations(organization_list_id,id,organization_id);
-- PAWSQL_IDX1838207686 can be used to do a COVERING index LOOKUP with condition(organization_lists_organizations.organization_list_id = 1), and SORT AVOIDANCE for (order by organization_lists_organizations.id desc).

CREATE INDEX PAWSQL_IDX0087834561 ON organizations(id,eb_id,lf_id);
-- PAWSQL_IDX0087834561 can be used to do a COVERING index LOOKUP with condition(organizations.id = organization_lists_organizations.organization_id).



